# Windows search indexes no items

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

For a while, using the windows explorer search to find files by their file name has been returning no items, even when I know there is a match.  I looked into it and it appears that the index contains no items.  I've removed and readded the include locations, restarted the windows search service, changed the index location and it still shows 0 items indexed.  Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?  (Or even an temporary alternative to search the file system, by file attributes only.  Not content)

Windows 7 Pro 64-bit

I'm using Window Security Essentials only for virus protection. (I found internet posts indicating 3rd party virus software appearred to cause this problem for them)

Comment: Can try read this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309173/en-us

Comment: That one is about searching file content.  I don't even get any matches for files names.  I'll clarify in the question.  Thanks tough.

Comment: I suggest you open Index Options from Control Panel, then click Advanced, click the File Types tab. Make sure that ost is checked.

Comment: OST is indeed checked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I feel Microsoft really let me down with the new explorer interface. I am now using a 3rd party software called ["Search Everything"](http://www.voidtools.com/) to search for file names.

Comment: Excellent.  That will be great as an interim fix at least.  Super fast search too.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem on Google Drive and DropBox on Windows 8.  I suspect (don't know why) that it is to do with 64-bit Windows and C++ redistribution packages, but I can't find a solution.  Solved it by switching OFF search and just running searches longhand.  What a pain!